# Format kusto `summarize percentiles` result

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a kusto query like so:

```
BuildRuns  
    | where FinishTime >= todatetime("2023-01-16T18:32:00.000Z") and FinishTime <= todatetime("2023-02-16T18:32:59.999Z")  
    | extend DurationInSecs = datetime_diff("Second", FinishTime, StartTime)  
    | summarize percentiles(DurationInSecs,50,75,90)
```

This outputs a table of the percentiles in seconds. Awesome. But how do I format the output into m:ss (minutes:seconds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/format-timespanfunction

for example:

```
print seconds = 125
| extend as_timespan = seconds * 1s
| extend formatted = format_timespan(as_timespan, "mm:ss")
```

| seconds | as_timespan | formatted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 00:02:05 | 02:05 |

and

```
range seconds from 1 to 3500 step 1
| summarize (p50, p75, p90) = percentiles(seconds, 50, 75, 90)  
| extend p50_as_timespan = p75 * 1s, p75_as_timespan = p75 * 1s, p90_as_timespan = p90 * 1s
| extend
    p50_formatted = format_timespan(p50_as_timespan, "mm:ss"),
    p75_formatted = format_timespan(p75_as_timespan, "mm:ss"),
    p90_formatted = format_timespan(p90_as_timespan, "mm:ss")
```

| p50 | p75 | p90 | p50_as_timespan | p75_as_timespan | p90_as_timespan | p50_formatted | p75_formatted | p90_formatted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1749 | 2624 | 3151 | 00:43:44 | 00:43:44 | 00:52:31 | 43:44 | 43:44 | 52:31 |

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. However, I'm still unclear on the kusto syntax of accessing the data returned by percentiles() in the block I quoted in order to do this manipulation.

Comment: you can use `summarize (p50, p75, p90) = percentiles(DurationInSecs,50,75,90)`, then reference `p50`, `p75`, `p90` individually